# How can I get events from calendar which contain a certain title?

Tags: ios, swift, events, calendar

I am pretty new to swift!
I was just wondering how I can get all the events from the calendar that contain the names:

My mood today was very happy, My mood today was happy, My mood today was very sad, My mood today was moderate, My mood today was sad.
Thanks in advance!

This is the code I have so far:

```
import EventKit

var titles : [String] = []
var startDates : [NSDate] = []
var endDates : [NSDate] = []

let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)

 for calendar in calendars {
            if calendar.title == "My mood today was very happy" || calendar.title == "My mood today was happy" || calendar.title == "My mood today was very sad" || calendar.title == "My mood today was moderate" || calendar.title == "My mood today was sad"{

                let oneMonthAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*3600)
                let oneMonthAfter = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: +30*24*3600)

                let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneMonthAgo as Date, end: oneMonthAfter as Date, calendars: [calendar])

                let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)

                for event in events {
                    titles.append(event.title)
                    startDates.append(event.startDate! as NSDate)
                    endDates.append(event.endDate! as NSDate)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        print("Title is \(titles)")
        print("Start dates are \(startDates)")
        print("End dates are \(endDates)")
```

Comment: what problem you are facing with this code ?

Comment: the arrays are empty

Comment: you have events of these names ?

Comment: do you know how to debug and check whats happening ?

Comment: I do have the events names in calendar

Comment: I have the calendar title stored in the calendar but it does not work

Comment: [EKEvent <0x6000031cd950>
{
  EKEvent <0x6000031cd950>
{  title =   My mood today was happy; 
  location =  (null); 
  calendar =  EKCalendar <0x6000016a47c0> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #1BADF8;}; 
  alarms =   (null); 
  URL =    (null); 
  lastModified = 2020-07-25 18:45:32 +0000; 
  startTimeZone =  America/Los_Angeles (PDT) offset -25200 (Daylight); 
  startTimeZone =  America/Los_Angeles (PDT) offset -25200 (Daylight) 
};